# Regex negation for a word is not working (Java 7)

Tags: java, regex-negation

I am trying to parse the string returned from a network device to see if there is an error.

The test I am using is if there is no word 'invalid' in the string received, then there is no error. I am unsure if the regex is correct.

```
Pattern noErrorsPattern = Pattern.compile("^(?!.*(invalid)).*$");   
Matcher noErrorMatcher = noErrorsPattern.matcher(receivedDataString);
if (!noErrorMatcher.matches()) {
    throw new Exception("input has error");
}
```

receivedDataString does not have the string 'invalid' in it. I checked it by pasting it into an editor and searching for it - it is not found.
Yet, stepping through in the debugger, the exception will be thrown.

-- clarification --
I simplified the problem description but that may have misled a bit. Details:
For each command, I have a 'FieldPattern' regex to extract data fields from the returned text, and another 'NoError' regex to check if there was an error. The NoError regex can be set precisely for a command like, "new entry added" so that if this string is found, then the operation did succeed. The regex for no occurrence of 'invalid' in the string is the default NoError pattern, if none was specified for the command.

Comment: Is receivedDataString a single line or several? You say you are using a text editor to search for the text in it. If the text is on several lines, try `Pattern.DOTALL`. Also, your regex is already anchored: use `.find()`, not `.matches()`.

Comment: yes it is on several lines. I shall try DOTALL. Should I do a `if(!noErrorMatcher.find()) { throw...}` Also please see details added.

Comment: @fge is this the simplest regex to say; does not contain 'invalid'? I want to also add not contain 'error' and was going to write `^(?!.*(invalid|error)).*$`

Comment: Well, you can skip the parens since you have no need for grouping (`^(?!.*invalid).*$`). And your second regex is valid, no problem with that. Here, however, the parens are needed, you need the grouping.

Comment: @fge - can you please post your comment as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you match multiple lines. And by default, the dot in Java's regular expressions does *not* match line terminators.

Therefore, you need to specify `Pattern.DOTALL` when you compile your regular expression.

Note: since your regex is already anchored, you could use `.find()` instead of `.matches()`, since the latter will anchor the regex (and one day, you may not want that).

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a regular expression here, you can use the [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method, i.e.

```
if (receivedDataString.contains("invalid")) {
    throw new Exception("input has error");
}
```

If you wanted a regex anyway, you could use `".*invalid.*"`. As mentioned in the comments, if your received string will span multiple lines then be sure to enable the [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag **or** use instead the regex `"(?s).*invalid.*"`.

Comment: I wanted to use a regex because the NoError pattern will change (please see details added above).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your logic is backwards. If the pattern matches, it contains the string "invalid", but you are throwing the exception when the string does *not* match. (Just calling the pattern `noErrorsPattern` doesn't make it a no-error pattern :).)

Your regex seems overly complex for the particular case you have posted. How about:

```
Pattern errorsPattern = Pattern.compile("invalid");   
Matcher errorMatcher = errorsPattern.matcher(receivedDataString);
if (errorMatcher.find()) {
    throw new Exception("input has error");
}
```

This is equivalent to `receivedDataString.contains("invalid")`, but allows for more general regex search, which you indicate you need for other cases.

Comment: `NoErrorString = "....";` If I do not specify the negation of 'invalid', how will I also pass in the positive case for no error, "new entry added"

Comment: @Anil - The pattern you are using will match if the response string contains the text "invalid" and will fail to match if the string does not contain "invalid". Is that really a no-error case?

Comment: I shall try your suggestion with the positive case for no error, "new entry added" and get back here.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand. What should my regex be to say 'does not contain the word invalid'? Otherwise for the positive case, one must specify the negation of "entry was added"; IMHO that is harder.

Comment: my original NoErrorPattern in my question works fine after using the DOTALL flag.

Comment: @Anil - You should write up your solution, post it as an answer, and accept it. It will show that the problem is solved and might help others facing similar problems. (Or ask fge to post the answer, since he (she?) made the suggestion initially.)

Comment: yes, that was also on my mind. I asked fge to post his comments as an answer. Thanks :)